# Historic (and current) borders of Miami, FL

Tags: data, census, united-states, administrative-boundaries, borders

I am working from Australia and am new to US mapping and Census data.

I am looking for historic boundaries of Miami (FL) from maybe 100-200 years ago.

Also current boundaries would be great - what does census.gov data mean when they refer to "Miami"? - the goal is to show spatial growth as well as population growth over time to compare Miami to Australian cities.

Comment: While you are waiting for an answer to your question you may want to review our previous Q&As that have the same tags as your first three http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data+census+united-states

Answer (score 1):

I just read an article about a new... app? created by the USGS, called the [Historical Topographic Map Explorer](http://historicalmaps.arcgis.com/usgs/). You can search or pan, click on the map, and it will show a timeline at the bottom listing the date of all available maps. The oldest for Miami seems to be 1950 though.

Another source mentioned in several answers elsewhere on this site is the [National Historical Geographic Information System](https://www.nhgis.org/).

Contacting the city directly, either GIS or perhaps a historic preservation department, may yield some data. Often current boundaries are available from either the city or county directly on their websites.

I'm not clear on your sub-question of 'what do they mean'. It depends on in what context I imagine. There is the actual city as well as the metropolitan area which would include other cities. And as cities expand over time, they often engulf and absorb surrounding towns and cities, so it would depend on *when* you ask as much as where.